# SetEnv httpd for use in PHP

Tags: php, apache, setenv

I'm attempting to set an environmental variable in Apache for later use in PHP.  I'm doing this by including a file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, which holds these contents:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "dev"
```

I've also added this line to `httpd.conf` file for testing:

```
SetEnv BATCHPATH /foo:/bar
```

Neither of these variables appear in PHP via `$_SERVER` or `$_ENV`, and I do not see them using `getenv("ENVIRONMENT")`.

I'm running Centos 7, have the `env_module` listed as (shared) under `httpd -M`, but also have `mod_suexec` listed there as well, which I've read may be overriding any user variables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I should note that I'd like it available as a global server variable.  Also, there currently is only one site running on the server.

Comment: @amarjitsingh this is ubuntu-like configuration. In centos there's no such folders.

Comment: @Csizzle, `service httpd reload`?

Comment: I did try sudo service httpd restart, several times througout the process

Comment: I also tried this in Debian via similar conf.d and .conf methods, restarted apache, and did not see the variables in SERVER, ENV, or getenv.

Comment: I've tried multiple methods, on multiple OS's, in multiple instances.  Tried to export the variable in /etc/sysconfig/httpd, and to no avail.  Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, as the online docs I've seen mention nothing of these sorts of problems.